# Generating custom linux kernel config

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I need to make a testing environment for my network-related application which should be close to the real linux host. In general it work but I have an issue with linux kernel building.

Right now I use config generated by `make defconfig` and some extra config changes I'm applying manually using `make menuconfig`. However defconfig enables a lot of drivers as modules which slows down kernel rebuild significantly. At the same time my qemu virtual machine have fixed number of devices which requires only some drivers which known before launching.

Is there any way to "disable all device drivers" in linux kernel config?